# C# Uncheck textbox when the text on the label has changed

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make the checkbox uncheck by itself when the text on a label changed?

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Price.Text == "?" ){ checkBox1.Checked = false}
    }
```

I dont know what I should put in the "?"

Comment: You should handle `TextChanged` event of your label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle `TextChanged` event of your label:

```
private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You can use any logic here, 
    //for example you can check if(label1.Text=="something")

    this.checkBox1.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: `Checked` assignment may need to be validated against the value of the label text - edit pending peer review.

Comment: @RobertFoster Thank you for your comment and edit, based on OP question **I dont know what I should put in the "?"** I'm not sure the OP wants this, I'll improve the answer and add a comment in code:)

Comment: Yes, I realised that too after my edit - your edit is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a public bool type variable

```
public bool DirtyBool = false;
```

Wherever you have written the code to change the value of the label you can make a new variable of type bool like this.

```
DirtyBool = true;
```

Than you can do it like this

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DirtyBool){ checkBox1.Checked = false; }
}
```

BTW `CheckedChanged` event will only get fired when the Check box is checked or unchecked thus the answer provided by @Reza Aghaei will be more suitable in your situation.

Comment: That's targeting the wrong event though - should be setting the `Checked` property of the target checkbox based on events of the other controls.

Answer (score 0):

You Checked check is being triggered at your CheckBox.CheckedChanged event. You must trigger it at Label's TextChanged event. Reza's answers is not complete, so you should do this:

```
YourLabel.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
{
if(YourLabel.Text == "?") yourCheckBox.Checked = false;
else yourCheckBox.Checked = true;
};
```